# How to get the color of a specific pixel from SDL_Surface?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to get the RGB/RGBA color of pixels from a SDL_Surface. I've found this code on the internet but it returns strange numbers (67372036 for a pixel that is 0 red, 0 green, 255 blue)

```
Uint32 get_pixel32(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels;
    return pixels[(y * surface->w) + x];
}
```

This it the code I've been using:

```
Uint32 data = get_pixel32(gSurface, 0, 0);
printf("%i", data);
```

I'm not sure if my pixels have a 32bit format but other pictures didn't work as well.

Comment: note that `y * surface->w` is _wrong_ many images have a "pitch" greater than their width.

Comment: @BradAllred pixels[(y * surface->w) + x] isn't wrong if the surface uses a 32-bit format.

Comment: @Nelfeal where is that guarantee written? Even if that were true you can still use `surface->pitch` which _is_ portable to other formats. Regardless, the OP made it clear he doesnt know the format and therefore cannot make such assumptions.

Comment: @BradAllred While I agree there is no written guarantee, I'm pretty sure it stands true. Look at `SDL_CalculatePitch` in SDL_pixels.c: `pitch = surface->w * surface->format->BytesPerPixel` if it's a 32-bit format. And my answer addresses the fact that it depends on the format. My point is just that the function itself isn't wrong.

Comment: @Nelfeal `SDL_CalculatePitch` is used when SDL is allocating its own pixel buffers (via `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` for example). `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom` will accept _any_ pitch you pass it. A real life example of this being greater than the width*bpp is having a giant sprite sheet image and many subimages that share pixels from the master. You will have many tiny surfaces with a pitch of `master->w * bpp - sub->w * bpp`. maybe doesn't matter to you or OP, but why mislead others?

Comment: @BradAllred Fair point. I was only thinking about "normal" SDL surfaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this code and it's working fine.

```
Uint32 getpixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
    int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    /* Here p is the address to the pixel we want to retrieve */
    Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;

switch (bpp)
{
    case 1:
        return *p;
        break;

    case 2:
        return *(Uint16 *)p;
        break;

    case 3:
        if (SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)
            return p[0] << 16 | p[1] << 8 | p[2];
        else
            return p[0] | p[1] << 8 | p[2] << 16;
            break;

        case 4:
            return *(Uint32 *)p;
            break;

        default:
            return 0;       /* shouldn't happen, but avoids warnings */
      }
}



SDL_Color rgb;
Uint32 data = getpixel(gSurface, 200, 200);
SDL_GetRGB(data, gSurface->format, &rgb.r, &rgb.g, &rgb.b);
```

Comment: Why is there only a byte order fix for formats with 3 bytes per pixel? Wouldn't every pixel format (except 1 byte per pixel formats, of course) need this same byte reordering on big endian systems?

Comment: @monkey0506: Because the 3 byte per pixel format does 3 separate memory accesses, which are then manually ordered and combined into a single machine ordered value. Contrast that with the 2 and 4 byte cases, which use a single memory access using the native machine ordering.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the color format of the surface, or [`SDL_PixelFormat`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat). You can follow what is presented on that page, or just use [`SDL_GetRGB`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRGB).

Comment: tried that but it didn't work as the get_pixel32 function only supports 32bit pixels and i figured out my surface had 8bit per pixel. found another function to get the pixel data for multiple pixel sizes.