# IMG_Load or SDL_Surface only has one RGB channel

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm trying to load an image file and grab the pixels from it, but it seems it only has pixels stored in the red channel and they don't match up with the original image.

I searched around and found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033971/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-specific-pixel-from-sdl-surface) on stack overflow. I ended up copy and pasting their solution in and it didn't work.

This is what I am expecting

[image: expectation]

This is what I get. Image is tiled.

[image: reality]

IMG_GetError() doesn't return anything. I've tried both jpg and PNG. Not sure what is happening here and would like some guidence.

```
Uint32 getpixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
    int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    /* Here p is the address to the pixel we want to retrieve */
    Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;

switch (bpp)
{
    case 1:
        return *p;
        break;

    case 2:
        return *(Uint16 *)p;
        break;

    case 3:
        if (SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)
            return p[0] << 16 | p[1] << 8 | p[2];
        else
            return p[0] | p[1] << 8 | p[2] << 16;
            break;

        case 4:
            return *(Uint32 *)p;
            break;

        default:
            return 0;       /* shouldn't happen, but avoids warnings */
      }
}

IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
SDL_Surface *  img_test;
img_test = IMG_Load("resources/stonetiles_003_diff.png");
    
if(!img_test) {
    printf("IMG_Load: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
}
    
    
int bpp = img_test->format->BytesPerPixel;
for (int i = 0; i < img_test->w; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img_test->h; j++)
    {
        Uint8  data = getpixel(img_test, i, j);     

        SDL_Color rgb;
        SDL_GetRGB(data, img_test->format, &rgb.r, &rgb.g, &rgb.b);
            
        printf("%d %d %d\n", rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output of rgb values

```
22 0 0
21 0 0
34 0 0
49 0 0
52 0 0
42 0 0
46 0 0
48 0 0
47 0 0
53 0 0
```

Comment: Looks like you're hitting case 3 in the code.  A p[0]<<16 or p[2]<<16 shifts off the size of a unit8_t and you lose the data before the 'or'-ing and promoting to Uint32 at the time of return.  Try `return ((Uint32)p[0]) << 16 | ((Uint32)p[1]) << 8 | p[2];`

Comment: Yup it hits case 3. Tried your suggestion and the r values are slightly different. However I have the same problem. No green or blue values and still appears as the gradient.

Comment: Add some debugging at the top of case 3, and `printf("p= %06x\n", (Uint32)p[0] | (Uint32)p[1] | (Uint32)p[2] );`  Or even `printf("p= %d %d %d\n",p[0], p[1], p[2] );` to see what you have there.

Comment: Tried both of them.

`printf("p= %06x\n", (Uint32)p[0] | (Uint32)p[1] | (Uint32)p[2] );` ->
`p= 00003f`

`printf("p= %d %d %d\n",p[0], p[1], p[2] );` ->
`p= 34 21 12`

The second suggestion is actually giving me the RGB values. I replaced SDL_GetRGB with that and it loads correctly.

What would your recommendation be? Use that or try and use SDL_GetRGB?

Comment: Right.  If the order is little endian, and you're on an Intel, which _is_ little endian, you don't need to change the values.... so the else case should have been `return *(Uint32 *)p >> 8;`  as the 3 bytes of p need to be in the lower 24 bits of the 32 bit value returned.

Comment: Actually, I may still be wrong, as I don't know what SDL internal format is being used, and that will be what SDL_GetRGB will want for 'data' to match the format in parameter 2 to be able to retrieve the RGB values. (parameter two to that function).  I expect that function already knows about what endian the pixel data is, for example.  See: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat -- the second example on that page shows how to get RGB and Alpha values from a format.

Comment: Ok, I used `return *(Uint32 *)p >> 8;` for the return statement of case 3. This time my red channel that is return is actually the green channel. Green and blue from  `SDL_GetRGB` are still 0. I also tried using the code from example 2 as suggested. But I end up in the same boat I did from the beginning. I am only able to get the red channel.